# iPod Touch G4 disconnects from Belkin N+ Router at random intervals

Tags: ipod-touch, wifi, router

I have an iPod Touch G4 and a [Belkin N+ Router F5D8235-4 v2](http://www.belkin.com/IWCatProductPage.process?Product_Id=459640), and for some reason the iPod Touch disconnects from the router at random intervals.

Checking the settings in the iPod, it will read that it is still connected to the router, but before I can access the internet again, I have to turn on Airplane mode and then turn it off again to get any program to work with the Internet again.

I've tried upgrading the firmware in the router, but that also doesn't seem to help.  I'm using the wiresless mode 802.11b&802.11g&802.11n in the 20/40MHz frequency.

Is there any way of fixing this issue?  It doesn't happen with any of the other devices that are connected to the router.

*[This post has been cross posted here](https://superuser.com/questions/227455/ipod-touch-g4-disconnects-from-belkin-n-router-at-random-intervals)*

Comment: Any luck so far resolving this?

Comment: @Ryan No, but I'm about to speak with Belkin about it.

Answer (score 2):

I have had this issue with the D-link router at home from time to time. My solution was to set a static IP and manually enter the device's IP, subnet mask, gateway IP, and DNS server IPs manually into the device.

Comment: Static ip check, giving it a try....

Comment: This is interesting...the same issue has just today cropped up with the same dlink and my new iPad...will update as I explore more options.

Comment: Got it fixed. My iPad somehow got a different IP from the router than was defined on device. Even though both were set to have .203, the router was routing packets to .205. Still unsure what happened, but the router needed a tune up of it's configuration anyways.